# Reverse Proxy: HTTPS forwarding to VM (OwnCloud)

Tags: http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, owncloud

I am running a few Virtual Box'es on my host - one of them is from OwnCloud. This allowed me to set it up really fast, and using PhpVirtualBox, I also have a nice tool for management.

I already know how to forward HTTP traffic to my VMs. They are all set up as NAT with their ports forwarded by scheme:

```
1VNNN
1: The master-range
V: Virtual Box ID. Basically an ID i choose.
N: Port
```

That means I have `12080` and `12443` for the OwnCloud box. And now I would like to forward HTTPS traffic. Here is what I did with regular HTTP:

`nginx/sites-available/owncloud`:

```
server {
    listen (...some ip...):80;
    server_name cloud.example.com;

    # Proxy
    set $REMOTE_PORT 12080;
    include basic_proxy;
}
```

`nginx/basic_proxy`:

```
# Proxy
# Really basic, does HTTP stuffles.
# @var $REMOTE_PORT : Remote HTTP port
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$REMOTE_PORT;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

And now I'd like to do it the HTTPS way. What'd be a good way to do so?

I am likely going to share a lot of configs like for proxy, PHP apps and such, which is why I made this into an external file immediately. Modularity is pretty useful.